# Error while computing maximum likelihood

Tags: statistics

I have a density given by $f_X(x / \theta) = \begin{cases} 
2\theta/x^3 & x\geq \theta \\
0 & x<\theta
\end{cases}$
with $\theta>0$.

I'm asked to compute the maximum likelihood of $\theta$. I have the likelihood function given by $L (\theta) = \displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^n f_{X_i}(x_i)= \displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^n f_{X}(x_i) = \displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^n 2\displaystyle\frac{\theta^2}{x_i^3} = 2^n\theta^{2n}\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^n\displaystyle\frac{1}{x_i^3}$.

Taking logaritms

$\ln L(\theta) = \ln \left(2^n\theta^{2n} \displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^n\displaystyle\frac{1}{x_i^3} \right) = \ln(2^n \theta^{2n})+\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n \ln( x_i^{-3} )$

Then

$\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \ln (L(\theta)) = \displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \ln(2^n \theta^{2n}) = 2n^2\displaystyle\frac{2^{n-1} \theta^{2n-1}}{2^n \theta^{2n}} = \displaystyle\frac{n^2}{\theta}.$

I can't maximize $\theta$ because no boundaries were given. I wanted to have $\displaystyle\frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta} = 0$ but this is not possible with the given function.

Comment: Your description of L isn't complete, because you haven't considered the two cases in the pdf. This is crucial: as you have written it, L increases with $\theta$, but L is only equal to the expression you wrote for $\theta$ less than a certain number.

Comment: The moral is to think before you differentiate. Which theorem about maxima of differentiable functions are you actually using? What does it say *exactly*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some (possibly typing) mistakes in the provided derivation. First, $$f(x|\theta) = \frac{\color{red}{2\theta^2}}{x^3},$$ when $x \ge \theta$. Second, $$L(\theta) = \color{red}{2^n \theta^{2n}}\prod_{i=1}^{n} x_i^{-3} \quad \color{red}{\text{for $\theta \le x_i$}},$$ and $\color{red}{L(\theta)=0}$ when $\theta > \min\{x_i\}$, where $i=1,2,\cdots, n$. Consequently,
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \ln(L(\theta)) = \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}(2n\ln(\theta)+\text{other terms})=\frac{\color{red}{2n}}{\theta} > 0, \quad \color{red}{\text{for $\theta \le \min\{x_i\}$ }},$$ and is zero otherwise.

Now use spaceisdarkgreen answer to establish $$\hat{\theta}_{\mathrm{MLE}} = \min\{x_i\}.$$

Comment: I don't follow your derivation.

If $L(\theta) = 2^n \theta^{2n}\prod_{i=1}^{n} x_i^{-3}$ why isn't $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} L(\theta)=  2^n (2n)\theta^{2n-1}\prod_{i=1}^{n} x_i^{-3}$ ?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. I meant to say $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \ln(L(\theta))$.

Answer (score 1):

The likelihood for one sample is an increasing function of theta until it suddenly drops to zero once $\theta>x.$ Similarly for $n$ samples, it increases until it suddenly drops to zero once $\theta >\min x_i.$ The MLE is thus $\min x_i.$